# dual map to the exterior multiplication

Tags: tensor-products

I came across with a concept problem which ask me to describe the dual map to the exterior multiplication $$m: \bigwedge^iV\otimes\bigwedge^jV\to\bigwedge^{i+j}V$$
by the formula independent of the choice of basis. Here $V$ is a vector space over a field $K$.

What is the definition of the dual of a mapping(multiplication)? I only know the concept of dual of a vector space $V$ over a field, which is the linear functionals on $V$. Does this dual map of the multiplication has something to do with the dual space?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Well, $m$ is a $K$-linear map of $K$-vector spaces, so the dual map is most likely referring to $\text{Hom}_K(K,m):\text{Hom}_K(K,\bigwedge^{i+j}V)\to \text{Hom}_K(K,\bigwedge^{i}V\otimes \bigwedge^{j}V)$

Comment: @xavier17, no: you have all your maps  backwards.

Comment: haha wow you're right sorry!  swap $K$ and $m$ etc. in my Hom's.  It's won't let me edit it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dual map of a linear map $u:E\to F$ is the linear map $u^t:F^*\to E^*:\psi \mapsto \psi \circ u$ , usually called the transpose of the map $u$ .
In your case the transpose of the linear map $m: \bigwedge^iV\otimes\bigwedge^jV\to\bigwedge^{i+j}V$ is a linear map $$m^t:(\bigwedge^{i+j}V)^*\to (\bigwedge^iV\otimes\bigwedge^jV)^*\quad (\bigstar)$$
In order to describe it concretely, I'll use the canonical isomorphism  $$(\bigwedge^{i+j}V)^*=\bigwedge^{i+j}V^*$$ and describe the corresponding linear map $$M:\bigwedge^{i+j}V^*\to (\bigwedge^iV\otimes\bigwedge^jV)^* \quad (\bigstar \bigstar) $$
This last linear map is easily described on decomposable vectors:

Given the linear forms $\phi_i\in V^*$  and the decomposable vector $\omega=\phi_1\wedge \dots \wedge \phi_{i+j}\in \bigwedge^{i+j}V^*$ the linear map $M$ transforms $\omega$ into the linear form $M(\omega)\in  (\bigwedge^iV\otimes\bigwedge^jV)^*$ determined by $$M(\omega):   \bigwedge^iV\otimes\bigwedge^jV\to K:(v_1\wedge\dots\wedge v_i)\otimes (v_{i+1}\wedge\dots\wedge v_{i+j}) \mapsto \det   (\phi_k(v_l))              $$ with $k,l$  in the range $1\leq k,l\leq i+j$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have a question. Why you define the final map $M(\omega)$ as $det$(an alternating map)? but not a just $\Pi_{k=1}^{i+j}\phi_k(v_k)$? Is it because the two wedges? But the middle is just a tensor(which do not need alternating but just multilinear is OK). So why should I define an alternating map?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have a map of vector spaces $f\colon V \to W$ over a field $k$ you can form the dual map $f^*\colon W^* \to V^*$. All this is is precomposition: take $\lambda\colon W \to k$ to $\lambda \circ f\colon V \to k$. Sometimes one denotes the duals by ${}^\vee$ instead of ${}^*$.

Some facts in the finite dimensional case that will probably be helpful: $(V \otimes W)^* \simeq V^* \otimes W^*$ and $(\bigwedge^k V)^* \simeq \bigwedge^k V^*$, although in both cases one really ought to write down the perfect pairing that makes this happen and verify that it works. A lot of this is worked out in [this handout](http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/diffgeomPage/handouts/tensor.pdf) of Brian Conrad's.

What is likely being asked is for you to take a "pure" element $\lambda_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge \lambda_{i + j}$ ($\lambda_p \in V^*$) and give some formula for its image under the dual map. I don't think it would be such a bad idea to pick a basis for $V$ and work everything out for the dual basis to that first; working it out for small dimensions or taking $j = 1$ to begin with might help also.